# Clojure: quote vs syntax quote evaluation order

Tags: clojure, quoting

I'm trying to understand quoting in clojure and came across [this article](https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html). While trying out the examples, I'm confused about the order of evaluation of quoting expressions.

```
`(~`'baz)
;; ↪ ('user/baz)

`(~'`baz)
;; ↪ ('user/baz)
```

Why do both the above expressions evaluate to `('user/baz)`? Shouldn't the first one evaluate to `('baz)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting an explanation into a code block because backticks mess up the formatting. Note that I don't use strict Clojure, mixing inputs with outputs, because it's easier to explain that way, at least for me.

```
`'bar and '`bar are the same because:

- 'bar is (quote bar)
  > `(quote bar) is (`quote `bar) which is (quote user/bar)

- `bar is user/bar
  > 'user/bar is (quote user/bar)
```